# The existence and uniqueness theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling to understand how and when to use this theorem to solve problems, and was wondering if I could get any tips here.

$y'=-y-2$ $, y(0)=0$

1. Determine $ø_n(t)$ for an arbitrary value of $n$.
2. Express $\lim_{n\to\infty}{ø_n(t)} = ø(t)$ in terms of elementary functions; that is, solve the given initial value problem.

I have no idea on what to do for the first question and I'm not sure on how I can solve the initial value problem. By using the separable method I end up with $\int\frac{-1}{y}\:dy =\int{-2\:dx}$ and that gives me $-\ln|y|=-2x+C$?

EDIT: I think I've managed to solve the initial value problem, making $C$ equal to $-1$.

I'm not sure if I actually have to use the theorem to solve these questions, but it's the name of the chapter in this book so I would assume so, it probably has something to do with the proof of the theorem.

Comment: What is $\varnothing_n(t)$ (or whatever it is; I $\LaTeX$ ified for the purposes of this comment . . .)

Comment: existence and uniqueness: if f and af/ay are continious in the rectangle R:|t|<=a, |y|=<b, then there is some interval |t|<=h=<a in which there exists a unique soluiton y=ø(t)  of the initial value problem

Comment: woah, I looked at the solution, dunno if it is correct, but if it is holy sh*t these questions are hard.

Comment: OK, I know these things can be difficult.  Now, what does the subscript $n$ mean?  Also, you might try a little $\LaTeX$, you can learn it at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics or in the notes accompanying this site; it would make things easier to understand . . . Anyway, let's keep up the dialog!  Cheers!

Comment: nvm, I found out what it means I think: Ø_n(t)= t^2 + t^4/2! + t^6/3! +...+ t^2n/n! it is from Ø(t)= integral 0(lower) t f[s,ø(s)]ds, and we have that ø_1(t)= integral 0 t 2s[1+Ø_0(s)ds=integral 0 t 2sds=t^2 and then it goes on for ø_2(t) and then u get Ø_n(t) :)

Comment: I do not understand what ∅n(t) means but the solution of your equation seems simple: (y-2)'=y-2 so d/dt{ln(y-2)}=1 or ln(y-2)-ln(y(0)-2)=t  or y-2={y(0)-2}exp[t]=-2exp[t] or  y(t)=2{1-exp[t]}.

Comment: how came  (y-2)'=y-2 ?

Comment: you're given $y' = y - 2$, so since $y' = (y - 2)'$ we can put these two equations together to yield $(y - 2)' = y - 2$.